# Evaluating the integral of $\sqrt {x^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having trouble with finding the integral of the following. 
I am looking for a step by step explanation so that I understand the process, rather than the answer only.

$$\int \sqrt{x^3} \,\mathrm{d}x $$ 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the power rule? It might help to represent $\sqrt {x^3}$ as $x^{3/2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Considering $ \sqrt[n]{x^m} = x^\frac{m}{n}$ (difference of notation), you can rewrite $ \sqrt[2]{x^3} = x^\frac{3}{2}$ and your integral as

$$ \int x^\frac{3}{2} dx $$
and apply the [integral power rule](http://www.mathbootcamps.com/power-rule-integrals/) (see note as well)

$$ \int x^\frac{3}{2} dx = \frac{2}{5}x^\frac{5}{2} + c = \frac{2}{5} \sqrt{x^5} + c $$

Note:  The power rule of integration is simply,

$$ \int x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + c $$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\int \sqrt{x^3}dx$ write $\int x^{\frac{3}{2}}dx$ so you'll get $\frac{2}{5}x^{\frac{5}{2}}+c$

Comment: $+ \ C{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You should also explain the rule you apply: coefficient $\tfrac25$ is a little cryptic for a learner, don't you think ?...

Comment: Thanks I usually thinks it's common and forget to write it unless necessary.@tilper

Comment: @tilper for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: If he knows basic rule for integration then I don't think but if OP doesn't then I'll add it.@JeanMarie

Comment: @ItiShree, I'd be hard pressed to find a calc 1 or 2 instructor who'd say that isn't necessary for indefinite integrals.  :)  $\quad$

Comment: From necessary I meant when c=0 @tilper :P

Comment: Sure, but that's the point of indefinite integrals.  $C$ is arbitrary and we don't know what it is until further info is given.